# query specific range prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I want to query the number of the increased "connections_per_ms" every 1 hour at a specific range at a specific date ex:

from "1.5.20, 12:00" to "2.5.20 12:00",
query the increased connections every 1hour

so if at 12:00 I had 4000 connections and at 13:00 I have 4300 connections

should return 300

and do that in a range

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the relation of the time dimension and range in your question, but maybe this would work (part with label is optional and can be removed):

```
sum(increase(your_metric{your_label='your_label_value'}[1h])
```